# Passing parameters to next page in multipage template

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a simple JQM/phonegap app which displays a list of news articles from mySQL and then passes a parameter to the next page to display the full news article.

I am using a multi-page template and cannot seem to pass the value correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>News</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

     $.getJSON('getnews.php', function(data) {                                                               
         if( data ) { 
          $('ul#articleList').empty();
          $.each(data, function(key, val){ 
              $('ul#articleList').append('<li><a href="#two" data-parm="'+ val.id +'" id="news-param">'+ val.title +'</a></li>');                             
            });
            $('ul#articleList').listview('refresh');

            } else {
                 $('ul#articleList').html('<li><a href="">No news articles</a></li>');
            }



        });


    </script>
</head> 


<body> 

<!-- Start of news list: #news-list -->
<div data-role="page" id="news-list">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>News</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" >  
          <script>

         $('#news-param').live('click',function(){
            var parm = $('this').data('parm');
            alert (parm);
             $("#showparam").html(parm);
        });

        </script>

        <ul id="articleList" class="icon-list"></ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /news list -->


<!-- Start of news article page: #two -->
<div data-role="page" id="two" data-theme="b">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Two</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">    
        <h2>News Article</h2>
        <div id="showparam"></div>

        <p><a href="#news-list" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Back to news listing</a></p> 

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /news article page -->


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have a typo in your code:

```
$('this').data('parm');
```

should be

```
$(this).data('parm'); //no quotes around this
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/D4s9Y/)**

Comment: Well spotted. That worked and all running perfectly.  Thank you.